# PHP - Submit button does nothing

Tags: php, email

I know this has been asked tons of times. But my submit button isn't working on an Email script I have.

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))

 {

$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
mail("necro@gophobia.com", $subject,
$message, "From:" . $email);
echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}
else
 {
 echo "<form method='post' action='http://cogameservers.com/home/contact'>
Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
Message:<br />
<textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
</textarea><br />
<input type='submit' />
</form>";
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help =]

---

*Edit*
When I say the submit button doesnt work. I mean it does nothing at all.

Comment: It looks like it should work fro me. What browsers have you tried, and is anything output to the Javascript Console? Do you have any client scripts running on the page?

Comment: What is happening? what are the symptoms?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Is there a PHP error?

Comment: `print_r($_REQUEST['email'])` and post the results. What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Double correction. Sorry guys. It is still continuing to do nothing when you click submit.

Comment: I just did print_r($_REQUEST['email']), There is no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check your HTML source code](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcogameservers.com%2Fhome%2Fcontact). It is completely messed up:

- there is a second opening `<html>` tag
- your `<head>` contains many lines of code that should be placed in `<body>` instead (such as `<div id="loginmodal" class="reveal-modal">`)

The browser does it best to overcome errors, but sometimes it gets lost when there are too many serious errors.

There are other errors, check what the validator outputs. Fix your HTML code, check that the validator is happy, then try again submitting your form.

The correct syntax for conditional comments is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In your case it should be:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!<![endif]-->
```

But your code currently is:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8] <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Anyway, since there already is an opening `<html>` tag earlier, it will cause an error: there can be only one `<html>` tag in the page.

Comment: What you see is a lot of jQuery plugins used for a modal dropdown. It was meant to be placed there. As to how I have two <html> tags? I see nothing of the sort.

Comment: Check the link I gave in my answer. The validator displays the line number for each error it encounters. There are indeed 2 opening HTML tags in your code.

Comment: Also. Using HTML validators on my site is out of the question. I have my whole site based on a PHP structure. Any validator includes the WHOLE site for any page as can be seen why I get so many duplication errors and other things.

Comment: Your PHP code outputs HTML code. If your HTML code is a mess, then your webpage won't work. Using the validator is the best way to spot errors in your HTML code. Using PHP is not an excuse for outputting completely invalid HTML code.

Comment: I'm looking at your HTML source and @Jocelyn is right. It's messed up. You'll need to fix it. Take this for example `<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->` The comment is ended to early and it opens a second `html` tag

Comment: In my source code. It shows the comment is not ended early. I don't understand.

Comment: I fixed my own issue. Thank you though.

Comment: You fixed nothing, there still is a serious syntax error with `HTML` tag. See my answer, I just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Contact line 45 has problems.  Use in browser debuggers like Firebug and check the console.